# Chart.js chart flickering when re-opening page

Tags: javascript, cordova, chart.js, mustache

I am loading a view file via mustache.js into a `<div>` container.

In that view, I have a canvas element within a dedicated div on which I am showing my chart using Chart.js

```
<div>
    <canvas id="gesundheitsverlauf-chart">
        Your web-browser does not support the HTML 5 canvas element.
    </canvas>
</div>
```

When I draw the chart for the first time, everything is fine. When I navigate away from the view to another view and then back, the chart is flickering (disappearing and reappearing quickly).

I have already turned of animation, and set the following:

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

What can I do to remove the flickering?
Is there any way to check if the chart has already been drawn on to the canvas? In that case I would stop it from a new drawing until the user requests it.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you are redrawing chart on the same div or canvas use `.destroy();`

Eg: To create

```
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

and To destroy before redrawing

```
window.myPie.destroy();
```